# Auto validate a function parameter using a method

Tags: python, function, parameters, flask

Is there any way to attach a decorator to the following function in Python 3 in order to save having to call `_is_valid_token()`?  I will be passing this static value into every function as a key to call the API via SSL and wish to simplify my code.

```
# Constants
TOKEN = '7632ba6a-0609-4b0c-a92e-9107bec88941'


@app.route('/my-game-server/api/v1.0/create_new_game/<token>/<player1>/<player2>/<rules>',
           methods=['GET'])
def create_new_game(token, player1, player2, rules):
    # Create
    """Creates a new game from scratch

    :param token: Unique value that verifies the caller is valid
    :param player1: Name of the first player
    :param player2: Name of the second player
    :param rules: String representing the rules to be used in the game
    :return: UUID representing the game id that has been created
    """
    # Validate token
    _is_valid_token(token)

    # Create game
    game_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    return game_id


def _is_valid_token(token):
    """Validate that the caller has a legitimate call into the service

    :param token: Unique value that verifies the caller is valid
    """
    if token != TOKEN:
        abort(400)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`url processor`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/urlprocessors/).

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def _is_valid_token(endpoint, values):
    if 'token' not in values:
        return

    if values['token'] != TOKEN:
        abort(400)
```

This runs for all routes, but only does the validation if the route actually has a 'token' value.  There are of course many other checks you could do beforehand to limit validation, such as basing it on specific endpoint names, but this is the most general function.

---

You can also just decorate the specific functions you want to validate.  This would be more general than the Flask solution.

```
def _is_valid_token(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(token, *args, **kwargs):
        if token != TOKEN:
            abort(400)

        return f(token, *args, **kwargs):

    return decorated

@app.route(...)
@_is_valid_token
def create_new_game(token, ...):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always define your own function decorator! This article talks more about decorators in Python:
http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html

You could define your decorator as a function like so:

```
def validate_token(func):
    def newfunc(token, *args):
        _is_valid_token(token)
        return func(token, *args)
    return newfunc

...
@validate_token
def create_new_game(token, player1, player2, rules):
    ...
```

Now whenever `create_new_game` is called, it'll call `_is_valid_token` first, as long as it has the decorator.